# Model not found though it exist Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-api

I am having a hard time finding what I missed but my model is not detected though it exist. I created the controller,model and migration through "php artisan make:model VacationLeave -m -c". I am using Laravel 8 API and I have this in my controller [image: VacationLeaveController]

This is my Route Api
[image: Route API]
And the post man result trying to post a request[image: Post man result]

What I've tried so far:

1. Renaming and Reinstalling Controller and Model
2. composer dump-autoload

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. To import models into controller just use "App\Models\ModelName" instead of "App\Http\Models\ModelName"